# Size of char pointer

Tags: c

```
int main()

{

    int i;

    char *names[5] = {"Miri", "Tali", "Ronit", "Avigail", "Shlomit"};

    //Printing all the names:

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)

        printf("%s\n" , names[i]);

    return 0;

}
```

How come its print the whole name? does names[0] (for example) shouldn't print only M?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`names` is array of character pointers. So `names[0]` is `char *` pointing to `"Miri"`.
And similarly for other subsequent items.

Comment: So the compiler assign a char array to save all the letters, then assigning the pointer with the first letter as the pointer to the name?

Comment: @newhere, generally compiler will store `"Miri"` and other strings in memory and initialize the array with those pointers. But actual implementation depends upon compiler.

Comment: For extra fun, consider that those string literals are actually immutable, even though their type is `char[*]`, and they may share space.

Answer (score 0):

In your program `names` is an array of pointers to `char` as already was mentioned in **Rohan**'s answer, so to print the first character you should first access the array element and then the the `0`th character

```
printf("%c\n", names[i][0]);
```

also note that the appropriate specifier is `"%c"` for one character, since `"%s"` expects a pointer to `char`, which should point to a null terminated sequence of bytes, i.e. a string.

Aditionally you should declare the array like

```
const char *names[5] = {"Miri", "Tali", "Ronit", "Avigail", "Shlomit"};
```

because the elements are string literals, and should not be modified. So using the `const` specifier you prevent acidentally doing that.